# RestKit (v0.21) - Core Data: Mapping JSON without key path

Tags: json, core-data, mapping, restkit

I'm having some trouble mapping this JSON message into corresponding core.data entities ...

JSON:

```
{
"d": [
    "Copenhagen (CPH), Denmark",
    "Copenhagen, Roskilde (RKE), Denmark",
    "Comitan (CJT), Mexico",
    "Cooperstown (COP), New York, United States",
    "Copan (RUY), Honduras",
    "Copiapo (CPO), Chile",
    "Copper Center (CZC), Alaska, United States"
]
}
```

Core.Data Entity ...

```
@interface MMAirportSimpleResult : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@end

@implementation MMAirportSimpleResult
@dynamic name;
@end
```

RestKit is configured like this ...

```
RKEntityMapping *airportSimpleResultMapping =
[RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([MMAirportSimpleResult class]) inManagedObjectStore:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore]];

[airportSimpleResultMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKAttributeMapping attributeMappingFromKeyPath:nil toKeyPath:@"name"]];

RKResponseDescriptor *airportSimpleResultDescriptor = 
[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:airportSimpleResultMapping pathPattern:@"services.asmx/CompleteAirportsSimple" keyPath:@"d" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addResponseDescriptor:airportSimpleResultDescriptor];
```

This is the error I'm getting from RestKit:

```
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Expected a dictionary representation' ...
```

I've tried mapping with a simple NSObject class and that is working perfectly with the above configuration ... 

What am i doing wrongly with the core.data entity ...? 


Thanks in advance